# Select2 dropdown menu (ajax,initSelection) error "options.results is not a function"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

I am using select2 plugin(ivaynberg.github.io/select2).

I am trying to display a dropdown(select).

Data getting via ajax, for this I create 2 servlets.

1. Dropdown menu url: '/testPr1/servlet1'

Return:
`[{"id":1,"text":"Genre1"},{"id":2,"text":"Genre2"},{"id":3,"text":"Genre3"},{"id":4,"text":"Genre4"}]`

2. Init data url: '/testPr1/servlet2'

Return:
`[{"id":1,"text":"Genre1"},{"id":2,"text":"Genre2"}]`

I create hidden element for select2 (and set init value)

Select film genre from list:

```
<input type="hidden" id="film_genre_cbox" style="width:600px" value="1,2" />
```

Then I get started with creating dropdown

```
var select_config2 = {
            minimumInputLength: 0,
            allowClear: true,
            placeholder: "Select film genre",
            tags: true,
            ajax: {
              url: '/testPr1/servlet1',
              dataType: 'json',
              type: "GET",
              quietMillis: 0,
              data: function (term) {
                return {
                  term: term
                };
              },
              initSelection: function (element, callback) {
              },
              results: function (data) {
                return {
                  results: $.map(data, function (item) {
                    return {
                      text: item.text,
                      id: item.id
                    }
                  })
                };
              }
            }
          };

    $("#film_genre_cbox").select2(select_config2);
```

It works well, select exclude Genre1 and Genre2 as init value

But I want to see these two genres as selected elements in input, like this:

[image: picture1]

And then I tried to init select2 via ajax

```
var select_config1 = {
    minimumInputLength: 0,
    allowClear: true,
    placeholder: "Select film genre",
    tags: true,
    ajax: {
      url: '/testPr1/servlet1',
      dataType: 'json',
      type: "GET",
      quietMillis: 0,
      data: function (term) {
        return {
          term: term
        };
      }
    },
   initSelection: function (element, callback) {
          var id = $(element).val();
//        alert(id.toString());
          if (id !== "") {
              $.ajax({
                  url:'/testPr1/servlet2',
                  dataType: "json",
                  type: "GET",
                  quietMillis: 0,
              }).done(function(data) {
                  alert(data.toString());
                return callback(data);
              });
          } else {
              callback([]);
        }
      },
      results: function (data) {
        return {
          results: $.map(data, function (item) {
            return {
              text: item.text,
              id: item.id
            }
          })
        };
      }
  };
$("#film_genre_cbox").select2(select_config1);
```

As result I get init selection as want

[image: picture2]

But when I start to dropdown I get no menu (Genre3,Genre4)

**and error “Uncaught TypeError: options.results is not a function”.**

Libs that I use

```
jquery-2.1.4.js
/select2_v3.5/select2.js
select2_v3.5/select2.css
```

Where is the mistake?

Comment: You missed the 3rd image. See how I added the first two. Where are "options" that might have "result" ?

Comment: As i'am a new user, system allow add only 2 pictuters,but i get failed with pictute order.Now order is correct.
In "results: function (data)" i return options.result, in initSelection i also tried to do something like this "return callback({results:data});" but it cause the same error.